# What is the difference between compile(export_all) and export([all/0]) in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

Seems like the two has the same effect when used as in all of the functions are exported when you compile your code. Is there a difference between the two ? Does `export([all/0]).` export all of the functions without needing to be compiled ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I read Pouriya's answer several times, and it wasn't until I read it the third time that I understood what `Pouriya` was trying to say.

What `Pouriya` is trying to say is that `export([all/0])` doesn't do what you think it does.  Rather, it exports a single function named `all()`, and no other functions in the module will be exported.  That is simple to test:

```
-module(my).
-export([all/0]).

all() -> ok.
go() -> ok.
```

In the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)
1> c(my).
my.erl:5: Warning: function go/0 is unused
{ok,my}
```

Right away you get a warning: because `go()` isn't exported, which means you can't call it from outside the module, and because no functions inside the module call `go()`, the function `go()` is "unused".  In other words, `go()` will never execute, so the compiler is wondering why you defined `go()` in the first place.

But, suppose you can't figure out what that warning means (and after all it's just a warning):

```
2> my:all().
ok

3> my:go().
** exception error: undefined function my:go/0
```

> Seems like the two has the same effect

Nope:

```
-module(my).
-compile([export_all]).

all() -> ok.
go() -> ok.
```

In the shell:

```
/erlang_programs$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2>
```

No warning about `go()` being "unused".  And:

```
2> my:all().
ok

3> my:go().
ok

4>
```

no error when you call `go()`.